# I have a html form that is basically vertical but i really have no idea how to make two text fields on the same line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float, customization

I have a html form that is basically vertical but i really have no idea how to make two text fields on the same line. For example the following form below i want the Size,Width,Height feilds on the same line  rather then one below the other.

```
<form class="cart" action="https://***********.com/product/stitchcount/" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div id="wccf_product_field_master_container">
        <div id="wccf_product_field_design_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_select wccf_field_container_product_field_select">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_design"><span class="wccf_label">Design </span></label>
            <select name="wccf[product_field][1376]" id="wccf_product_field_design" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_select wccf_product_field_select" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1376">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="flat">Flat</option>
                <option value="3d">3D</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_size_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_select wccf_field_container_product_field_select">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_size"><span class="wccf_label">Size</span> <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
            <select name="wccf[product_field][1249]" id="wccf_product_field_size" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_select wccf_product_field_select" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1249" data-wccf-required-field="1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="inch">Inch</option>
                <option value="mm">MM</option>
                <option value="cm">CM</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_width_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_width"><span class="wccf_label">Width</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1250]" id="wccf_product_field_width" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1250" data-wccf-character-limit="3"><small class="wccf_character_limit" style="display: none;"><span class="wccf_characters_remaining">3</span> characters remaining</small></div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_height_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_height"><span class="wccf_label">Height</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1251]" id="wccf_product_field_height" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1251">
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_no_colors_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_no_colors"><span class="wccf_label"># of Colors</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1378]" id="wccf_product_field_no_colors" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="# of Colors" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1378">
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_sewn_on_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_select wccf_field_container_product_field_select">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_sewn_on"><span class="wccf_label">Design to be sewn on</span></label>
            <select name="wccf[product_field][1377]" id="wccf_product_field_sewn_on" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_select wccf_product_field_select" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1377">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="flat_goods">Flat Surface (hoop or flatbed) </option>
                <option value="fineshed_caps">Finished Caps</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_placement_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_placement"><span class="wccf_label">Placement</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1375]" id="wccf_product_field_placement" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1375"> <small>(hat,left chest, full back, etc.)</small></div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_fabric_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_fabric"><span class="wccf_label">Type of Fabric</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1374]" id="wccf_product_field_fabric" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="width: 100%;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1374">
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_format_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_text wccf_field_container_product_field_text">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_format"><span class="wccf_label">Required Format</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="wccf[product_field][1373]" id="wccf_product_field_format" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_text wccf_product_field_text" style="100% width;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1373"> <small>(DST,PES,HUS,JEF,NGS,EMB, etc)</small></div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_instructions_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_textarea wccf_field_container_product_field_textarea">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_instructions"><span class="wccf_label">Instructions</span></label>
            <textarea name="wccf[product_field][1252]" id="wccf_product_field_instructions" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_textarea wccf_product_field_textarea" style="100% width;" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1252"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="wccf_product_field_upload_container" class="wccf_field_container wccf_field_container_product_field wccf_field_container_file wccf_field_container_product_field_file">
            <label for="wccf_product_field_upload"><span class="wccf_label">Upload </span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="wccf_ignore[product_field][1253]" id="_wccf_product_field_upload" value="">
            <input type="file" name="wccf_ignore[product_field][1253]" id="wccf_product_field_upload" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_file wccf_product_field_file" data-wccf-quantity-based="1" data-wccf-field-id="1253">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5e32d067d8b8f">Stitch Count quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity_5e32d067d8b8f" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="230" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CSS:

```
#wccf_product_field_width_container, #wccf_product_field_width_container {display:inline-block; max-width:50%;}
```

Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Concern has been resolved by using the float left attribute.  Thanks for your kind help.